# Exception when connecting to jBPM 6.2 via Remote EJB Client API

Tags: jbpm

**I can not connect to jBPM 6.2 via Remote EJB Client**, I always have exception like 

*EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:jbpm-console, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1a198243*

My understanding is that issue may be caused by one of followings: 

**1- Bad configuration of WildFly for remoting?** 
The running Wilfly does not have port 4447 opened (tested via telnet), but documentation writes default port for remoting is 8080, which responds.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

**2- jBPM Remote EJBs are not correctly deployed on the server?** 
I don't see any *DeploymentServiceEJBRemote, ProcessServiceEJBRemote, RuntimeDataServiceEJBRemote,* etc. in the startup log trace. 
Do I configure something more in some WildFly .xml config files ?

**3- Wrong module name in JNDI string?** Currently tryied with: 
*jbpm-console*, which seem to be active (WildFly says *"Successful version handshake completed for receiver context..."* before throwing *"No EJB receiver available for handling..."* exception). 
*sample-war-ejb-app*, which refers to nothing deployed... But is given in jBPM example and tests. 
Has the remoting only to be used with a custom EJB written by myself, as the "sample" world could mean ?

I will be happy to get inputs from some hard-skilled developers from the Community.
Thanks by advance,
Renaud 


Additional inputs for context:

For the tests, I'm using an out-of-box built of jBPM and following the official documentation from http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMIntegration.html#d0e19856 and on test package from github /droolsjbpm/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-services/jbpm-services-ejb/jbpm-services-ejb-client. 

jBPM engine is working well with some alive processes deployed from Nexus and remoting with Client REST API perfectly works on all features. 

In standalone-full.xml file used at startup, there is no definition for JNDI:1099 nor Remoting:4447 in socket-binding-group. But adding Remoting seems to change nothing. 

Dependencies used in my client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-services-ejb-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```